# Left trim: Remove characters after last instance of a number

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have text in Excel that is a combination of numbers, letters, and symbols.

```
010-038-310-1500-93745
010-038-310-3000-xxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx
010-038-???-????-?????-????????
010-038-190-3109-?????-87655467-????????
010-038-310-3101-xxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx
010-038-xxx-3103-xxxxx-xxxxxxxx-49359661
```

I would like to remove all characters in the text that come after the last instance of a number:

```
010-038-310-1500-93745
010-038-310-3000
010-038
010-038-190-3109-?????-87655467
010-038-310-3101
010-038-xxx-3103-xxxxx-xxxxxxxx-49359661
```

Is there a way to do this with a formula in Excel?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For data in **A1**, in another cell, enter the **array formula**:

```
=LEFT(A1,MAX(IFERROR(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)))),0)))
```

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

Comment: That is a great formula, took me a while to peel it apart but I am not used to using array formulae. What confuses me now is that it appears to work in my excel 365 just fine without being entered as an array formula, I guess the array is just contained within the max function?

Comment: @JustinDoward For what it's worth, it does **not** seem to work for me as a non-array formula in Excel 2016.

Comment: Hi @Gary's Student ,,  unfortunately it's not working for me, returns `01` from all cells ,, [Check this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2hpzugwxy9ywlw3/Test1.xlsm?dl=0) !!

Comment: Hi @Gary's Student,, I've fixed the issue it should be an array (CSE) formula rather than shown above !!

Answer (score 3):

A UDF to do the same:

```
Function LNum(Target As Range) As String

Dim i As Long

For i = Target.Characters.Count To 1 Step -1
If IsNumeric(Target.Characters(i, 1).Text) Then GoTo MyExit
Next i
MyExit:
LNum = Left(Target, i)

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: First version had some extraneous code.

Comment: This one is working properly ,, +10 ☺

Answer (score 1):

I don't have excel installed, but same syntax seem to apply as in google sheets. Very simple regex should be easy to understand.

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,".*\d")
```

Regex captures anything but must end with a digit.

[image]

Can anyone with Excel please verify syntax is the same?

Comment: The syntax isn't the same, there's no built in regex spreadsheet functions in Excel. That said, it's very easy to whip up a custom function in VBA using the Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions library.

Comment: Looked some wrong infromation then. Feels like regex is the way to go when you read the problem description. However I can see that  scripting in VBA might be a too high of a threshold for some.