# Make hyperlink in Excel only display word (single part of hyperlink)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, hyperlink

I have hyperlinks that refer to different items and the initial part of the hyperlink is all identical. What I am trying to do is put or display that hyperlink using only what comes after the last "=" in the link.
ie the links are in a format like this

https ://mysite.com/in/?track=default&page=123&camp=4NFG&room=**lounge**

I want them to display as just "**lounge**" but still being hyperlinked.

The only way I can do it that I know of is to manually do each one but I have close to a thousand links so that isn't a good option.

Any ideas?

Comment: does every url of yours end with ``&room=sometext``?

Comment: Note that you have a space in that hyperlink that prevents it from working, if that is true for the page you are working on you will need additional formula to remove the space.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a formula pointing at the cells currently containing the hyperlink:

```
=HYPERLINK(A2,RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-MAX(IFERROR(FIND("=",A2,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A2)))),0))))
```

The formula is modified from: 
[Left trim: Remove characters after last instance of a number](https://superuser.com/questions/1549219/left-trim-remove-characters-after-last-instance-of-a-number/1549220?noredirect=1#comment2356108_1549220)

[image]